# merge datatable as array of json with condition asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, web

i have two datatables
DataTable dt1 and
DataTable dt2
dt1 is filled with products and dt2 is filled with product flavors
both tables have a common id that is "productcode"

with newtonsoft json serializer I'm getting the response as

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "productcode": 1676,
      "type": "BEER BOTTLE-24*325ML",
      "image_url": "http://localhost/images/temp.png"
    },
    {
      "productcode": 1677,
      "type": "RED FIGHTER CAN-24*250ML",
      "image_url": "http://localhost/images/temp.png"
    },
    {
      "productcode": 1678,
      "type": "POWER ENERGY CAN 24*330ML",
      "image_url": "http://localhost/images/temp.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

and

```
{
  "flavor": [
    {
      "productcode": 1676,
      "ProductFlavorID": 9351,
      "Flavor": "APPLE"
    },
    {
      "productcode": 1676,
      "ProductFlavorID": 9352,
      "Flavor": "STRAWBERY"
    },
    {
      "productcode": 1673,
      "ProductFlavorID": 9353,
      "Flavor": "respery"
    },
    {
      "productcode": 1678,
      "ProductFlavorID": 9354,
      "Flavor": "RUMMAN"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to join this jsons with condition where json1 productid= json2 productid and result like

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "productcode": 1676,
      "type": "BEER BOTTLE-24*325ML",
      "image_url": "http://localhost/images/temp.png",
      "flavor": [
        {
          "productcode": 1676,
          "ProductFlavorID": 9351,
          "Flavor": "APPLE"
        },
        {
          "productcode": 1676,
          "ProductFlavorID": 9352,
          "Flavor": "STRAWBERY"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "productcode": 1677,
      "type": "RED FIGHTER CAN-24*250ML",
      "image_url": "http://localhost/images/temp.png",
      "flavor": [
        {
          "productcode": 1677,
          "ProductFlavorID": 9353,
          "Flavor": "respery"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "productcode": 1678,
      "type": "POWER ENERGY CAN 24*330ML",
      "image_url": "http://localhost/images/temp.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

how can I archive this...

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to get the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apporach this situation with [linq](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/sample-linq-queries), when iterating every product you can set flavors from dt2 by filtering with Where method.

Simple example would be like this:

```
using System.Linq;

products.ForEach(p => {
    p.flavors = flavors.Where(f => f.productcode == product.productcode).ToList();
});
```

[Where method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0)